# Subtitle player encoding problem

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, subtitle

I have been using [Greenfish Subtitle Player](http://download.cnet.com/Greenfish-Subtitle-Player/3000-13632_4-75748013.html)  with Wine on Ubuntu to view subtitles in online video streaming sites for months, and it serves me well. However, it is often that when the source of subtitles is from China, the software malfunction (it also happens in Windows so it's not a problem of Wine). I guess it is an encoding problem, because I checked that all .srt files, they look fine in notepad++. And I can barely search any new alternatives that could resolve the encoding problem. Any suggestions?